# Can we use logical conditions with is not null keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am developing a payroll management system using oracle for self learning purpose.
Following is a snippet of a code for the stored procedure to update and insert data for employee table where p_department_id_1 and p_department_id_2 are two parameters to procedures of IN type.

I encountered an error on the second line as given below, I don't know whether i can use OR with IS NOT NULL or not. 
Kindly tell me what is the actual mistake i did here.

```
      v_status                                     :=0;
      IF p_department_id_1 OR p_department_id_2 IS NOT NULL THEN
        p_department_id_1                          :=NVL(p_department_id_1,p_department_id_2);
        p_department_id_2                          :=NVL(p_department_id_2,p_department_id_1);
        IF p_department_id_1 AND p_department_id_2 IS NOT NULL THEN
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          INTO v_department_count
          FROM department
          WHERE department_id  =p_department_id_1
          AND department_id    =p_department_id_2;
          IF v_department_count>0 THEN
            v_status          :=1;
          END IF;
        END IF;
      ELSE
        v_status:=1;
      END IF;
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: should be: if p_department_id_1 is not null or p_department_id_2 is not null

Comment: I would say that you should have some logical expression for `p_department_id_1`

Comment: @DCookie I am getting two errors on second line of code 
1) PL/SQL statement ignored
2) expression is of wrong type

Comment: Yes, it was trying to evaluate p_department_id_1 as a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF p_department_id_1 IS NOT NULL AND p_department_id_2 IS NOT NULL THEN

Comment: This is not the same thing.  Should be OR.

Comment: I tried this but it gives an error that I can't use p_department_id_1 and p_department_id_2 as an assignment target

Comment: @PiyushM - that's a completely unrelated error, from another line. Those must be `IN` parameters to your procedure; which means you can't change their values. You either need to make them `IN OUT` if you want the caller to see the changes, or use local variables.

Comment: @AlexPoole I got my answer. Thanks :)